# Can RestEasy serialize a POJO for a @GET method?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

We use Resteasy and have problems figuring how to call some @GET methods.

If the interface for the method only has simple parameters, there is no problem. Ex:

```
@GET
@Path("/test/{myparam}")
public FacetQueryResultImpl testMethod(@PathParam("myparam")String myparam);
```

But if we try to use a POJO as the parameter, it seems RestEasy is not able to serialize it as querystring parameters. Ex:

```
@GET
@Path("/testGet")
public FacetQueryResultImpl testMethod(ParamPojo myparam);
```

or

```
@GET
@Path("/testGet")
public FacetQueryResultImpl testMethod(@QueryParam("myparam")ParamPojo myparam);
```

(with, ParamPojo.java:)

```
public class ParamPojo
{
    private String name;
    private String description;
    (...)
}
```

When we try this, sometimes the services are not found and sometimes we get a "A GET request cannot have a body." exception.

Using @POST we are able to use a POJO has the parameter, but some of our methods don't modify anything on the server, and therefore should use @GET.

A workaround is to "explode" the ParamPojo, and use all of its properties as separated parameters for the method. But this removes the "Easy" part of "RestEasy", doesn't it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must use the `@org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.Form` annotation on your method parameter.
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html_single/#_Form

Example:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.Form;
import org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockDispatcherFactory;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpResponse;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCase {
    @Path("/")
    public static class Service {

        @Path("")
        @GET
        public String get(@Form ValueObject vo){
            return vo.getParam();
        }
    }

    public static class ValueObject {
        @QueryParam("myparam")
        private String param;

        public String getParam() {
            return param;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addSingletonResource(new Service());

        MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("/?myparam=somevalue");
        MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

        Assert.assertEquals("somevalue", response.getContentAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks eiden, it's appreciated!

Comment: note that sending data in GET requests is against the REST philosophy, see the "official" answer from Roy Fielding here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body/983458#983458

Comment: @Gregor The example above does not send any data in the request body.

Comment: sorry you're right @eiden I wrongly assumed the form data was sent in the body.

Answer (score 3):

For binding the multiple queryParam into a single object we need to add `@Form <POJO CLASS>` as a arguments in response method. It works fine for us.

```
@GET    
@Path("/")  
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response search(@Form CatalogSearchRequest reqObject) {
    System.out.println("Entered into service" + reqObject.getAttribute());
}
```

POJO class should contain `@QueryParam("")` for every attributes, for example:

```
@QueryParam("pageSize")
public Integer pageSize;

@QueryParam("page")
public Integer page;

public Integer getPageSize() {
    return pageSize;
}

public void setPageSize(Integer pageSize) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
}

public Integer getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(Integer page) {
    this.page = page;
}
```